# Specifying the Table on a HasMany() relationship mapping in FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a mapping in FluentNHibernate for a HasMany relationship and I'd like to specify a Table on it to override the default Table that nHibernate will look in to find those objects that I have many of. Does that make sense?

So lets say I have a table for Invoices and a table for InvoiceItems and lets say I have table called InvoiceItemsTwo.

I have a class for Invoice and a Class for InvoiceItems as well, and their mappings are pretty straight forward. I'd like to specify in my mapping for Invoice, that it should look for it's items in InvoiceItemsTwo instead of the default InvoiceItems.

So my mapping of that relationship looks like this

```
HasMany(c => c.InvoiceItems).Cascade.SaveUpdate().Table("InvoiceItemsTwo");
```

But this doesn't work. I keep getting an error from my website at runtime that says Invalid object name 'InvoiceItems'.

Why is it ignoring the fact that I am explicitly specifying the Table in my mapping on the relationship?

I tried dumping the mapping at run time and it's being setup something like this

```
<bag cascade="save-update" table="InvoiceItemsTwo">
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you specify in InvoiceItems mapping Table mapping as InvoiceTwo?

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5450304/handling-a-one-to-many-relationship-with-value-types-in-fluent-nhibernate)

Comment: Ahh thanks Cole. I looked before I posted this but I couldn't find anything that seemed to be similar. Yeah he is dealing with the same problem of trying to override the Table in the mapping, looks like he didn't have much luck either. It was kind of frustrating to find out it's just nopt supported, especially after both nHibernate mappings XML and fluentnhibernate both let you configure it that way. nHibernate just chooses to ignore that setting... :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `table` attribute applies only to many-to-many relationships, not one-to-many.

Comment: ... and elements and composite-elements as well

Comment: Hmm, Does it make sense to us it for One-To-Many relationships? I mean it seems pretty inherently useful, could it be added? I'm essentially just starting out when it comes to nHibernate so I don't know if there is even a way to request feature changes like this...

Comment: @Yarx: no, it does not make sense. In one-to-many relationships, *by definition* the table is defined by the "many" side.

Comment: Yeah you're right, when I think about the way DB design works and the way the relationships are defined, it would have to be that way. It doesn't make any sense to let it be overridden in the relationship definition. I'm working with a preexisting database so while it might appear to be a way to make this easier to work with it's not the way databases work.
Thanks for the advise :-)

Comment: I'd have to disagree. I have a need to utilize views because of some complex query logic, so it would make sense for me to be able to override the table on a `HasMany` so I could point it to a view.

Answer (score 0):

you can't specify a different table in your mapping class. Fluent NHibernate uses the class mapped on the property list (InvoiceItems).
If yoy want to use another class to map your details table you must create a InvoceItemsTwo class and map it in your master table class.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* map the list as composite-element instead of a one-to-many relation and then map it to another table. But it is *not a good idea*. Consider that NH needs to know where to store an object which is in memory. So it may happen that the object is stored in the wrong table.

- Either store all the InvoiceItems in separate tables using composite-element instead of one-to-many and components instead of many-to-one (however this is called in Fluent).
- Or store all the InvoiceItems in the same table and use regular references.